# In Html how to have element keep space when it has no value

Tags: html, css

A form is presented to server, at the start is no error

```
        <main>
            <form action="/start" method="post">
                <input type="image" value="Fix Songs" name="fixsongs" src="style/images/fixsongs.png" title="Fix Songs">
                <input type="image" value="Monitor Watch Folder" name="watchsongs" src="style/images/watch_folder.png" title="Monitor Watch Folder">

                <p>
                    <label for="folder">
                        Selected Folder 
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder">
                    <br>
                </p>
            </form>
            <p>
                <br>
            </p>
```

if user submit forms and server finds an error then the form is presented with a h1 element representing the error. The problem is then everything below the h1 is shifted down from where it was originally, how do I preserve some space for the h1 element even when there is no error so the rest of the page doesnt shift down when an error occurs

```
<h1 style="color:#FF0000;">
            No folder has been selected
        </h1>
        <main>
            <form action="/start" method="post">
                <input type="image" value="Fix Songs" name="fixsongs" src="style/images/fixsongs.png" title="Fix Songs">
                <input type="image" value="Monitor Watch Folder" name="watchsongs" src="style/images/watch_folder.png" title="Monitor Watch Folder">

                <p>
                    <label for="folder">
                        Selected Folder 
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder">
                    <br>
                </p>
            </form>
            <p>
                <br>
            </p>
```

Comment: Change the `visibility` property of the `<h1>`? That will allow you to not display the content of the `<h1>` while still taking up the normal amount of space as if it was being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply insert an empty `h1` element at he top, like

```
<h1>
  &nbsp;
</h1>
```

Or you create a "hidden" element with an invsible header for the form, like

```
<h1 style="visibility:hidden;">
  My Form
</h1>
```

The latter is semantically better...

In both cases it would be necessary that the form verification script uses the already existing `h1` to display the error, so you should also give it an ID or a class, so that the script can adress that tag and insert the error warning.

Here they are both in a snippet - but as intended, you won't see anything:

```css
body {
  background: #beb;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  &nbsp;
</h1>
<h1 style="visibility:hidden;">
  My Form
</h1>
<p>A paragraph below the invisible headers</p>
```

Comment: Thankyou that makes sense

Comment: but I find the visibility method doesnt seem to work, the nbps; one does.

Comment: hmm - I added a snippet with both, don't know why it doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a margin on the form itself, and then use a `span`, with a `font-size` set instead of a `h1` tag, like so:

```
<span style="font-size: 24px;">Your error here</span>
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">
<form action="/start" method="post">
    <input type="image" value="Fix Songs" name="fixsongs" src="style/images/fixsongs.png" title="Fix Songs">
    <input type="image" value="Monitor Watch Folder" name="watchsongs" src="style/images/watch_folder.png" title="Monitor Watch Folder">

    <p>
        <label for="folder">
            Selected Folder 
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder">
        <br>
    </p>
</form>
<p>
    <br>
</p>
</div>
```

You will always have a space at the top of your form then.